# jQuery call same method on click of different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code, which on click of div element, an action takes place. 
I want to add the same click action `Canvas.showContentDoc(d);` to the **href** in the `#document` element.

I want the same action to take place if the user clicks on `<i class='fa fa-angle-double-down'></i>` , how can I achieve this?

```
for (node in obj.nodes) {
    var d = obj.nodes[node];
    var color_document = "blue"
    jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: 'document' + d.id,
        class: 'document',
        click: function (d) {
            Canvas.showContentDoc(d);
        }
    }).appendTo(title)

    $('#document' + d.id).append("<span class='fa-stack fa-1x'>  <i class='fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x' style='color:rgba(110,130,34, 1)'></i><i class='fa fa-file fa-stack-1x' style='color:" + color_document + "'></i></span> : " + d.label + " (" + d.id_doc + ")<a href='#'> <i class='fa fa-angle-double-down'></i> </a> ");                    

    Canvas.selectedNodesInfos[nodes_iteration + id_start]['label'] = d.label;

    nodes_iteration += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the html output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as [this](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in jQuery:

```
$("selector1, selector2, selector3").on("click", function(){
   Canvas.showContentDoc(d);
});
```

---

Check it on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxzu0Lxf/) or Try this demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#button_1, #span_1, #anchor_1").on("click", function(){
 sameMethod();
});

});

function sameMethod(){
 alert("same method called.");
    console.log("same method called.")
}
```

```css
.clickable{
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<button id = "button_1" class = "clickable">
Click Me
</button>


<span id = "span_1" class = "clickable">
Click Me
</span>

<a href="#" id = "anchor_1" class = "clickable">Click Me</a>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.querySelector()` to add an event listener, like this:

```
document.querySelector('li.fa.fa-angle-double-down').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Canvas.showContentDoc(d);
});
```

Here's a very simple example:

```js
document.querySelector('li.fa.fa-angle-double-down').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Clicked!');
});
```

```html
<li class="fa fa-angle-double-down">List item</li>
```

Comment: how do I integrate it into my code? can you please help with it?

Comment: @passion Sure, just copy the code at the top of my answer (with your `Canvas.showContentDoc(d);` function call in it) and put it at the bottom of your JavaScript file. You're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `<i class='fa fa-angle-double-down'></i>` in `<a>`

Example: `<a href="#" onclick="Canvas.showContentDoc(d);"> <i class='fa fa-angle-double-down'></i></a>`

Although I believe that going JS all the way is better see @dsharew answer